# Terminator lose focus on tab/page switch on Ubuntu 20

Tags: command-line, 20.10, terminator

I recently reinstalled my Ubuntu virtual machine, upgrading it to the version 20.10.

I'm now facing a very annoying bug when using Terminator.

When I switch between tabs or I switch back to terminator from another software, very often the focus is lost and if I input something nothing happen.
Only when I click on the terminal all the keyboards buttons I have pressed are instantly executed.

On Ubuntu 16 I never had this problem using terminator.

I already tried to reinstall it, but it didn't help and I didn't find any other cases on the internet describing this behavior.